# Using a permutation test to test for differences in the median between two groups when distributions of the variable of interest are not equal

Tags: median, permutation-test

in the following, I will define (1) the hypothesis I wanted to test, (2) the method I used, and (3) the problems that I feel are present. My dataset consists of measures of one dependent variable for two groups that are equal in size.

(1) *Hypothesis*: I hypothesized that the median value of a variable is higher in group A than in group B.

(2) *Method*: I reshuffled the groups whose medians I want to compare 5000 times and calculated the difference of medians for each of these permutations. In doing so, I assumed that the null hypothesis states that the distribution of the dependent variable is equal in both groups (Otherwise I would not be allowed to reshuffle the observations under the null hypothesis). Then I compared the observed median difference with the distribution of median differences under the null hypothesis.

(3) *Problems*: The permutation test that I used assumes that the distribution of the dependent variable is equal in both groups under the null hypothesis. Looking at the data, however, the two distributions look quite different (which implicates that the population distribution of those variables is not the same in the two groups).

**Question 1**: Can I still use the test I described to test for a difference in medians even though the assumption of equality of distributions seems to be violated? Or is there another method that I can use to compare medians which does not assume equality of distributions under the null hypothesis?

**Question 2:** Furthermore, am I right that if I do not reject my null hypothesis, I will have to conclude that the distributions in the two groups are equal (because the test assumes this equality and is not significant)? This seems counterintuitive to me because the distributions look so dissimilar. In fact, if I use the difference of median as a test statistic, the test seems not to detect differences between distributions even though equality of distributions is assumed under the null hypothesis (I tested this by constructing very different distributions with equal medians. If I use the difference of medians as a test statistic and run a permutation test, the result is not significant).

Comment: Re Question 2: When you test the hypothesis that the medians are equal and do not reject it, *all* you will conclude is that you may proceed to assume the medians are equal.  You may *not* conclude the distributions are the same!  Re Question 1: Bootstrapping will work here.

Comment: Thank you. So is it not appropriate to use a permutation test if there is reasonable doubt regarding the assumption of equal distributions and should I rather use bootstrapping?

Comment: I'm not sure bootstrapping will be good.  In a small simulation I have found that the Wilcoxon rank sum test--even though it evaluates a slightly different null hypothesis--can be substantially more powerful than a direct comparison of medians.

Comment: Regarding what you said about problems, It doesn't matter whether or not the data appears not to fit the null hypothesis. The purpose of the test is to see if the statistical evidence is strong enough to reject. If that is the case it will show up that you will reject the null hypothesis.

Comment: Hey Michael, thank you for the reply. My problem is that I assume something that I do not even test (but which seems unplausible in light of the data), namely that  that the distributions in both groups have the same shape (not only the same median). This assumption has to be made because of the reshuffling as I described in my question. I am wondering if this is "allowed".

Comment: I dispute your premise. Unless you want a conclusion relating only to a location shift, it is not necessary that the data show very similar-shaped distributions for a permutation test. More generally you need exchangeability *under the null*, but you don't know that the null is true (and for a point null it's very unlikely to actually be the case); it's an assumption you're making under a counterfactual. You make it by considering your knowledge of the variables and the circumstances, not by looking at the data. It may be that whatever shifts the median also tends to impact the shape ...ctd

Comment: ctd... e.g. consider test scores on a fairly easy test (being integers scored out of 100). Does it matter whether we replace a large poster that is mostly showing blue colors on the wall with one showing mostly orange colors during the test? Scores for the blue group are mostly in the 75-90 range, though there's a good fraction of scores in the 90s. Clearly if scores were to increase for the orange group, the distribution would push up harder against the 100 boundary and the shape will necessarily change at the same time (we'd expect that they'd tend to become more left skew and less variable)

Comment: Does that shape change invalidate a permutation test of the median (or the mean or whatever else)? Not at all. If the change of poster had no effect - i.e. if the null were exactly true - we would indeed expect that exchangeability would hold. The fact that we might see a difference in the sample shapes tells us nothing about the suitability of that assumption -- it's exactly what we expect under our alternative.

Comment: This was a nice illustration. I see what you mean. Now I realize that I rather do not fully understand the logic of a permutation test. Consider, the example that you gave with the test scores. Let us assume that the test scores are, in fact, higher in the orange group. Then I necessarily construct a hypothetical distribution that does not exist by using a permutation test and draw from this distribution (namely a mix of the two actual distributions which consists of the higher and lower scores of the orange and blue group, respectively) ... ctd

Comment: ctd... Now I compare my observed difference with a distribution of median differences which is a result of this hypothetical distribution. Wouldn't it be more appropriate to bootstrap samples from the two groups individually (without mixing them) and construct a distribution of median differences this way? This way I would use the individual samples to construct a distribution of median differences (which are a better representation of the reality than a mix of the two distributions). Is there some error in my reasoning?